# How to search multiple api services

Tags: api, angular, typescript, search

I am developing a search engine with angular 2. 
Therefore I use APIs from multiple platforms.

It works if I call the search function from every api service manually.

But is it possible to do the same foreach api service?

Every api service has the same function:

```
search (query: string): Observable<Array<SearchResult>> { ... }
```

In the UI I want to separate the results by tabs.

Therefore every api service has a title:

```
public title: string = "the title";
```

For storing the search results locally I have a class that is extended by every api service. This class has helper functions etc.

Comment: It would be cool to use something like `foreach (let service of apiServices) --> service.search()`

Comment: I do not know angular, but in Java i would build a `Map` that maps the title to the `Observable` instances...

Comment: since you want to display the results by tab, why not just build a component that holds the content of a tab and does the search to one of the APIs?

Comment: every service has an observable `searchResults`

Comment: If I hit the search button I want to search every api. But when I click on a tab I can see the results from another api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the behaviour you need you can use **merge**, **concat** or **forkJoin** to merge multiple streams into one.

The code would look pretty much the same.

For example using **merge** in order to merge 2 streams into one.

If you have a list of apis you need to call for the search. Your code would look like this.

```js
let apis: string[] = [];

let observables = apis.map(api => search(api)); // get an array of observables

let merged = observables.reduce((previous, current) => previous.merge(current), new EmptyObservable()); // merge all obserbable in the list into one.

merged.subscribe(res => doSomething(res));
```

This article might be [helpful](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/combining-multiple-rxjs-streams-in-angular-2.0).